# Is there something similar to Python requests' Sessions for Paho MQTT?

Tags: python, paho

I'm reading the [documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/paho-mqtt/1.1#id17) for Paho MQTT's `Publish` module, and thinking of my application in which I might have to publish many `single` messages, each with similar keyword arguments. The calls look similar to the following:

```
paho.mqtt.publish.single('dummy_topic', payload=dummy_payload, qos=0, retain=False,
       auth={'username': "dummy_username", 'password': "dummy_password"},
       hostname=config['mqtt_host'], port=int(config['mqtt_port']), tls=dummy_tls)
```

In order to keep my code DRY, I'm trying to think of a way to persist the keyword arguments across different `single` commands.

For HTTP requests, Python's requests module has the [Sessions object](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/) which allows one to do this. Is there something similar for Paho MQTT, or shall I instead use something like `partial` from the [functools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html) module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already identified the solution, I think.  The `functools.partial` function should give you whaat you want.  For example, the following code:

```
from functools import partial

def myfunc(arg, kw1='foo', kw2='bar'):
    print 'arg:', arg
    print 'kw1:', kw1
    print 'kw2:', kw2

newfunc = partial(myfunc, kw1='hello', kw2='world')

newfunc('somearg')
```

Produces this output:

```
arg: somearg
kw1: hello
kw2: world
```

Applying that to your example, you would do something like:

```
publish_single = partial(payload=dummy_payload, qos=0, retain=False,
   auth={'username': "dummy_username", 'password': "dummy_password"},
   hostname=config['mqtt_host'], port=int(config['mqtt_port']), tls=dummy_tls)
```

And call it like:

```
publish_single('some_topic')
publish_single('another_topic')
```